# Plotting characteristics of antenna radiation in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, polar-coordinates, bessel-functions

I need to plot this function [image]

```
theta = (-pi:0.01:pi);
f = 3*10^9;
c = 299792458;
da = 2;
```

Here's my code, but I'm not sure it's correct. I dont know where exactly dot mark should be. How to set X-Axis in degress?

```
beta = (2*pi*f)/c;
const= (da*beta)/2; 
j= (cos(theta)+1).*(besselj(1,const*sin(theta))./(const*sin(theta)));
```

My another question is how to plot this function in polar coordinates.

I made something like this.

```
polar(theta,j);
```

Is it possible to rotate that function(by y-axis) to get 3D plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are quite right to me, although I wouldn't use the symbol `j` as a variable because (as `i` does) it is the symbol for the imaginary unit (`sqrt(-1)`). Doing so you are overriding it, thus things will work until you don't need complex numbers.

You should use element-wise operations such as (`.*`) when you aim at combining arrays entries element by element, as you correctly did to obtain `F(\theta)`. In fact, `cos(theta)` is the array of the cosines of the angles contained in `theta` and so on.

Finally, you can rotate the plot using the command `Rotate 3D` in the plot window. Nonetheless, you have a 2D curve (`F(\theta)`) therefore, you will keep on rotating a 2D graph obtaining some kind of *perspective view* of it, nothing more. To obtain genuine information you need an additional dependent variable (Or I misunderstood your question?). [image]

**EDIT:** Now I see your point, you want the [*Surface of revolution*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution) around some axis, which I suppose by virtue of the symmetry therein to be `theta=0`. Well, revolution surfaces can be obtained by a bit of analytic geometry and plotted e.g. by using [`mesh`](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html). Check this out:

```
  % // 2D polar coordinate radius (your j)
  Rad= (cos(theta)+1).*(besselj(1,const*sin(theta))./(const*sin(theta)));
  Rad = abs(Rad);  % // We need its absolute value for sake of clarity


  xv = Rad .* cos(theta);  % // 2D Cartesian coordinates
  yv = Rad .* sin(theta);  % // 2D Cartesian coordinates

  phi = -pi:.01:pi;        % // 3D revolution angle around theta = 0

  % // 3D points of the surface
  xf = repmat(xv',size(phi)); 
  yf = yv' * cos(phi);
  zf = yv' * sin(phi);

  mesh(xf,yf,zf)
```

[image]

You can also add graphics effects

[image]

this is done via

```
mesh(xf,yf,zf,'FaceColor','interp','FaceLighting','phong')
camlight right
```

and a finer angular discretization `(1e-3)`.

Comment: I want to get something like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/818/3dplot.png/

Comment: @daredesm, I got your point, around which axis do you want the revolution to be done? `theta = 0`?

Comment: Yes, I think theta = 0 is perfect, but is it possible to get more readable plot?

Comment: Is it possible to get this plot without using absolute function, because I think it cut off the back shape of the plot, so is it possible to remove complex part in another way?

Comment: @daredesm, of course, just remove it. It won't make difference indeed, though. For readability I would suggest just to plot(xv, yv), 2d but very effective.
Btw you may want to consider to accept the answer by using the tick sign on the left.

Comment: I get error ??? Error using ==> mesh at 80
X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex. 2D works fine, but mesh function returned error. EDIT: I think i get solution for this problem. real(argz) return real part of the complex number.